# Assigning a list to a subset of a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a df, and I want to assign a list to a specific column, based on a subset. So let's say this is my df:

```
d = {'foo':[100, 111, 222], 
'bar':[333, 444, 555]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

>>df
    bar   foo 
 0  333   100
 1  444   111
 2  555   222
```

I want now to assign `[1,2,3,4]` to the first and third row of `foo` column,
to get this df:

```
    bar   foo 
 0  333   [1,2,3,4]
 1  444   111
 2  555   [1,2,3,4]
```

I would expect something like:

```
df.loc[[0,2],'foo'] = [1,2,3,4]
```

to work, but it yields the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

Using `at`:

```
df.at[[0,2],'foo'] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Throws the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: because I have an app where I need to store in one column all the indexes that relate to the current row (and the number varies).

Comment: I don't think the app itself necessitates that, only how you've chosen to handle data. Putting lists into a df column is, almost always, a terrible idea

Comment: I agree. It is a small df though, and it will be easier for me to just implement it currently like that, and perhaps to think of another structure when I have time. The question is - is it possible.

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't test; does making the column `object` type first help?

Comment: It helps to convert them one by one (i.e. df.at[0,'foo'] = [1,2,3,4] works), but df.at[[0,2],'foo'] = [1,2,3,4] still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
indx = [0,2]
df.loc[indx, 'foo'] = pd.Series([[1,2,3,4]] * len(indx), index=indx)  
df
```

@MadPhysicist commented with a better solution
<strike>df.loc[indx, 'foo'] = pd.Series([[1,2,3,4] for _ in range(len(indx))], index = indx)</strike>

Output:

```
            foo  bar
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  333
1           111  444
2  [1, 2, 3, 4]  555
```

Comment: Do you need the series, or will `[[1, 2, 3, 4]] * 2` work just as well? I'm on mobile so can't check

Comment: Not too elegant but it seems it can't get much better :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yep, over thinking as usual.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did, you can upvote too. and [[1,2,3,4]]*2 didn't work for me.

Comment: There's also a missing bracket

Comment: Where? Can you post your full answer with [[1,2,3,4]]*2 please?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Your website in your profile down?

Comment: @BinyaminEven Just did.  You must align pd.Series and index parameter.

Comment: @ScottBoston. Yeah, it's been years since I bothered redirecting the IP correctly

Comment: @MadPhysicist Mind connecting with me on LinkedIn?   Thanks for considering.  BinyaminEven too.  Please find me on LinkedIn and connect.

Comment: You could also do a `dict` comprehension which would handle both the indexing and the build in one step. `pd.Series({i: [1,2,3,4] for i in indx})`

Comment: @HenryEcker Add that ans solution, I'll upvote it.